# Slide Pagination with Text for SuperSlides

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, slide

I'm trying to use both Superslides (https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides/) and Foundation 5 on a site.

I'm working with 4 slides, and want the navigation is not as "points" as is standard, but by text.

Ex .: The navigation will be by "Slide 1", "Slide 2", "Slide 3" and "Slide 4".

I didn't find a similar example, someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the answer to your problem or not.

I had the same issue its not very clear in the docs.

#### Step1

In your JS call both hashchange and pagination and set to true.

```
$('#slides').superslides({
    hashchange: true,
    pagination: true
});
```

#### Step 2

Add ids to your slider elements, so for example:

```
<img src="/imgs/people.jpeg" alt="home" id="home">
```

#### Step 3

Create a new navigation and style it as you please. Create links within each navigation item and link the HREF to the ids you have created.

```
 <nav class="extra-nav">
  <a href="#home" class="next">home</a>
  <a href="#about" class="prev">about</a>
  <a href="#end" class="prev">end</a>
</nav>
```

Your new navigation should now initiate the correct slides related to  the IDS you have used.